# Read int values from a text file in C

Tags: c, file, file-io, scanf, line

I have a text file that contains the following three lines:

```
12 5 6
4 2
7 9
```

I can use the `fscanf` function to read the first 3 values and store them in 3 variables. But I can't read the rest.
I tried using the `fseek` function, but it works only on binary files.

Please help me store all the values in integer variables.

Comment: You may get more helpful answers if you post your attempt, and explain how it's failing.

Comment: `fseek()` works fine on text files, but it is not clear why you'd need to use it to read the data you show.

Answer (score 60):

A simple solution using `fscanf`:

```
void read_ints (const char* file_name)
{
  FILE* file = fopen (file_name, "r");
  int i = 0;

  fscanf (file, "%d", &i);    
  while (!feof (file))
    {  
      printf ("%d ", i);
      fscanf (file, "%d", &i);      
    }
  fclose (file);        
}
```

Comment: With this method you don't print the last value. Delete the first `fscanf` and put the `printf` below the `fscanf`

Answer (score 9):

How about this?

```
fscanf(file,"%d %d %d %d %d %d %d",&line1_1,&line1_2, &line1_3, &line2_1, &line2_2, &line3_1, &line3_2);
```

In this case spaces in `fscanf` match multiple occurrences of any whitespace until the next token in found.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that you/he should check that he gets 7 returned from `fscanf()`, as otherwise something went wrong.