# Making loop without size in C on File

Tags: c

I want to calculate the sum and average on file.

```
for (i = 0; i > 50; i++) {
    fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &a);
    sum = a + sum;
    //printf("%d\n",a);
    count++;
}
```

but there is `50` as you can see that means I know how many integers that the file in it, I want to make a loop without that information. My loop should detect how many numbers in that file have.

As you can see I'm working on files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read int values from a text file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600797/read-int-values-from-a-text-file-in-c)

Comment: @DeiDei both answers totally awful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read with fscanf until you reach EOF (end of file)

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &a) != EOF) {
      sum+=a;
      count++;
}
```

Comment: That's not correct. Fscanf will return 0 on nondigit garbage

Comment: You're absolutely right that the return code should be checked to detect errors, but the question was on reading the whole file without knowing the size.