# How to convert from char to int in C reading from a file?

Tags: c, char, int

I am trying to read a file in C which has four numbers per line which represents coordinates of two points and then I am trying to find the distance between the two points. For this, I am reading the file lines one by one and I am getting it as a char array. Below is what I have done.

Output function which I am calling from read()

```
void output(char *buff){
    int co1,co2,co3,co4;
    co1 = atoi(buff[0]);
    co2 = atoi(buff[2]);
    co3 = atoi(buff[4]);
    co4 = atoi(buff[6]);
    printf("(%d,%d) lies on the %s,(%d,%d) lies on the %s, distance is %f.\n",co1,co2,quadrant(co1,co2),co3,co4,quadrant(co3,co4),distance(co1,co2,co3,co4));
```

}

Read function which I am calling from main.

```
int read(){
    FILE *file;
    char buff[255];
    file = fopen("point.dat", "r");
    while(!feof(file)){
        fgets(buff,255,file);
        output(buff);
    }
    return !feof(file);
}
```

Main function

```
int main()
{
    read();
    return 0;

}
```

But while doing so, I am getting below error.

```
[Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
```

The data of point.dat is

```
0 0 3 4
-1 -4 5 6
-1 3 -1 -2
4 -5 -5 -6
3 5 -6 5
0 5 5 5 
-5 0 0 -5
```

How can I convert char to array in output function? I tried stoi function too, but I got error that "stoi is not in scope"

Comment: The type of `atoi()` argument should be `const char *` and you are passing it a `char` type.

Comment: How can I change it to const char*?

Comment: You will want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) Also, don't *hardcode* filenames in functions. Either read it as input, or pass as an argument to `int main (int argc, char **argv)` and open and validate the file is open in the caller (`main()` here) and pass the open `FILE*` as a parameter to your `read()` function.

Comment: Sorry I am not able to get it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600797/read-int-values-from-a-text-file-in-c

Comment: I used that too, still, I got some error. @H.S.

Comment: A typical approach is to use `fgets` to read a line, and then use `sscanf` to extract the numbers from the line.

Comment: Or `while (fgets (buff, 255, file)) { if (sscanf (buff, "%d%d%d%d", &col1, &col2, &col3, &col4) == 4) { /* you have a good read and conversion of all points */ }`

Comment: Please make a [mre] of the attempt to use the functions made for this. Also, do not name your own functions (e.g. `read()` like existing functions).

Comment: You would need, e.g. `co1 = atoi(&buff[0]);` to fix your error (the `'&'` for all conversions), but never use `atoi()` in production code. It has *zero* error reporting capabilities and will silently return zero if, for example, you attempt `atoi ("my cow");` and you will never know an error occurred.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks, your & trick worked.

Comment: Also, rename your `read` function as `read_points` (or whatever you like other than `read()`), there is already a standard library function named `read`. It is legal to declare a function with the same name, but that is generally something you want to avoid `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your output() function, buff[i] is only one char which is not a string (char*) for atoi(). You should use strtok() to buff into tokens using the delimiter space and then pass each token to atoi().